# How do I set a default value for a parameter in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Controller

```
def index
  markers =  Marker.nearby(params[:lat], params[:lng], params[:radius])
end
```

### Model

```
def self.nearby(lat, lng, radius)
  approved.near([lat.to_f, lng.to_f], radius, units: :km)
end
```

### Routes:

```
resources :markers
```

### URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11111111&lng=10101010101&radius=20
```

#### Notes:

In the URL below we have 3 paramaters(lat, lng and radius). and i want the radius value equal to 1 (1 km). so when the user open (http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11.111111&lng=104.1010101) it'll get the default value with radius=1 (http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11.111111&lng=104.1010101&radius=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest setting the default value for radius in the model method. That ensures a consistent behavior even if you run it from the console or not using request parameters.

```
def self.nearby(lat, lng, radius)
  approved.near([lat.to_f, lng.to_f], radius || 1, units: :km)
end
```

Then `Marker.nearby(11.111, 104.010101, nil)` should set radius value to 1. Please notice this will only work when radius is nil, will fail for empty strings. if that's a concern you should check for present? like:

```
def self.nearby(lat, lng, radius)
  radius = radius.present? ? radius : 1
  approved.near([lat.to_f, lng.to_f], radius, units: :km)
end
```

Comment: yeah its corrects but if i didn't give the parameter, its failed.

http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11.530841042588&lng=104.916175883467

Comment: eg. the default value is 1, so when user input radius = 5. it will get 5 and if user don't put value, its should get the default value.

when radius = 5
(http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11.111111&lng=104.1010101&radius=5)

when radius is nil -> fetch the default value
(http://localhost:3000/markers?lat=11.111111&lng=104.1010101)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: thanks alot @Dario Barrionuevo . i have learn sth new. its working now. 

`def self.nearby(lat, lng, radius = 1)
    radius ||= 1
    approved.near([lat.to_f, lng.to_f], radius, units: :km)
  end`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fetch](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-fetch).

```
Marker.nearby(params[:lat], params[:lng], params.fetch(:radius, 1))
```

Comment: its working btw. i don't know its follow the best practice or not. i think its should be done in model. what do u think?

Comment: check the documentation of fetch that is in the link, I think it is the best practice. @max thank you for this piece

Comment: `def self.nearby(lat, lng, radius = 1)
    radius ||= 1
    approved.near([lat.to_f, lng.to_f], radius, units: :km)
end`

its working now. i think its should be done in the model. @max thanks for your answer anw. i have learned sth from you ^^

Comment: I cant really say that either is a best practice - it depends on how you are going to use it. Having a default of 1 might make sense in one context but not in others. If you add a model method I would make it a keyword arg and not ordinal.